# About Clang How to use inline assembly jump addresses

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I'm using Clang inline assembly and it always reports an error.

I have checked the intel assembly syntax and the msvc syntax for reference, but it still doesn't work.

How can I properly use inline assembly for call or jmp?

Prerequisite: no register assignment.

This is a small error URL that I compiled online
https://godbolt.org/z/KbKEqzMhK

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
void asm_test() {
__asm__(
R"(
.intel_syntax 
mov eax, eax
call 0x12345678
)"
);
}
```

Results on c86_64 clang 13.0.1 in:

```
<source>:7:1: error: invalid operand for instruction
call 0x12345678
^
<inline asm>:4:1: note: instantiated into assembly here
call 0x12345678
^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: You can't call an absolute immediate address in x86-64. It needs to be either relative, or a memory/register operand.

Comment: The bigger problem on x86-64, at least under SysV ABI, is that your call, or any other stack push, would clobber the red zone, which the compiler does not expect.  It is nearly impossible to safely do a function call from inline asm, at least if you expect that function to ever return.  Usually you should try to find some other way, e.g. a function written in pure asm.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, so please, does the inline assembly of intel syntax support defining variables?